# Can I return either a string or an `error` value via the same result?

Tags: go

i want execute function and return output results on variable, this is my actual code :

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "net/http"
    "io"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)


func downloadFile(url string) (err error) {

  resp, err := http.Get(url)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  // extrage numele fisierului din linkul redirectionat.
  finalURL := resp.Request.URL.String()
  parts    := strings.Split(finalURL, "/")
  filename := parts[len(parts)-1]

  out, errr := os.Create(filename)
  if errr != nil  {
    return errr
  }

  _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
  if err != nil  {
    return err
  }

  defer out.Close()
  defer resp.Body.Close()

  return filename
}

func main() {

  var url1 string = "https://transfer.sh/5e2iH/test.txt"
  var filename2 string = "test test test"

  filename2 := downloadFile(url1)

  fmt.Println( filename2 )

}
```

i want execute function downloadFile and return variable filename in variable filename2, return me this error, where im wrong ? im python developer, im sure to make stupid error :)

```
F:\dev\GoLang\gitlab\check>go run download.go
# command-line-arguments
.\download.go:37:3: cannot use filename (type string) as type error in return ar
gument:
        string does not implement error (missing Error method)
.\download.go:45:13: no new variables on left side of :=
.\download.go:45:13: cannot use downloadFile(url1) (type error) as type string i
n assignment
```

Comment: You are returning a string when it is expecting only an `error`. Your function should be `func downloadFile(url string) (string, error)` and every `return err` should be `return "", err` and your final return should be `return nil, filename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `error` like a string in the `downloadFile()` function, you should work with both variables. Golang is strongly typed and couldn't change the type of variable. You can use [interfaces](https://tour.golang.org/methods/10) for polymorphism but in this case, you need just return `err` and `filename` together like this:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "net/http"
    "io"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)


func downloadFile(url string) (err error, filename string) {

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // extrage numele fisierului din linkul redirectionat.
    finalURL := resp.Request.URL.String()
    parts    := strings.Split(finalURL, "/")
    filename = parts[len(parts)-1]

    out, err := os.Create(filename)
    defer out.Close()
    if err != nil  {
        return
    }

    _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    if err != nil  {
        return
    }

    return
}

func main() {

    var url1 string = "https://transfer.sh/5e2iH/test.txt"
    err, file := downloadFile(url1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println( file )

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go is strongly typed, so a function cannot return either an error or a string, depending on the case.

Luckily Go can return two variables from a function, and this is the preferred way to achieve what you want. Return a string AND an error, and return nil as the error if there isn't one.

The function signature should be

```
func downloadFile(url string) (filename string, err error) {
    .....
   // and since the variables are named in the signature, at the end you can just do:
   return
}
```

The caller function should check both the error and the returned string, just like your code is doing for example when calling `os.Create(filename)`

Comment: Just my opinion, but using named returns and having a bare `return` at the end will possibly cause him confusion down the road given that OP is new to Go.